# Group Matching Regex fails in Java

Tags: java, regex, bash, sed

Why does this regex pattern fail to match the groups in Java. When I run the same example with in a bash shell with `echo` and `sed` it works.

```
String s = "Match foo and bar and baz";
//Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Match (.*) or (.*) or (.*)"); //was a typo
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Match (.*) and (.*) and (.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

I am expecting to match `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`.

```
$ echo "Match foo and bar and baz" | sed 's/Match \(.*\) and \(.*\) and \(.*\)/\1, \2, \3/'
foo, bar, baz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to greedy nature of `.*`. You can use this regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Match (\\S+) and (\\S+) and (\\S+)");
```

Here this regex is using `\\S+` which means match 1 or more non-spaces.

**Full code**

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1) + ", " + m.group(2) + ", " + m.group(3));
}
```

Comment: Same as my code original code this outputs: `foo` on my system and then the program terminates. If you are sure that your example works, then I would say my Java runtime has a problem. So are you sure the example is correct?

Comment: I see my mistake. Seems I just take a break from coding. Thanks a lot. But in this case it also works with (.*), so it was not a greedy problem.

Comment: `.*` might work for this case but I recommend not using for 2 reasons 1. It is very inefficient and slow 2. It may grab more than you think it should grab

Comment: You are right, my example was a simplified one in which both solutions work. But in the actual code I had to use `\\S+`.

Comment: @ajb: Read all comments here, OP's example was a over simplified one.

Comment: OK, I understand that OP may have needed `\\S+`.  But it should be noted that the greediness or reluctance of regex constructs should _never_ affect whether a match is found, because of backtracking, unless there are non-backtracking constructs somewhere in the regex (`.*+`, `(?>...)`).  It would only affect how much text is matched and what goes into the groups.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to match the whole `String`, so

```
while (m.find()) {
```

will only iterate once.

That single `find()` will capture all the groups. As such, you can print them out as

```
System.out.println(m.group(1) + " " + m.group(2) + m.group(3));
```

Or use a `for` loop over the `Matcher#groupCount()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is correct, but you need to **print the different groups** and **not only the 1st**, ex:

```
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
    System.out.println(m.group(3));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a simple typo (`or` -> `and`):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Match (.*) and (.*) and (.*)");
```

**UPDATE**

To replace:

```
String s = "Match foo and bar and baz";
String replaced = s.replaceAll("Match (.*) and (.*) and (.*)", "$1, $2, $3");
System.out.println(replaced);
```

Comment: ah that was a typo, but your example also does not work